# Android: How to add every item that i've searched for to RecyclerView? (TextChangeListener and Room Database)

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to search in database using EditText, and then add items to RecylerView. I have problem with adding several items, because of TextChangedListener and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged. I can add just one item.  (Query need to be in thread). How to add every item that i was searching for?

CostDao.kt

```java
@Dao
interface CostDAO {

    @Query("select * from cost where name like :name")
    fun getByName(name : String) : List<Cost>
```

In MainActivity.kt i got this:

```java
 fun Threads() {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                count: Int, after: Int
         ) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(
                s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                before: Int, count: Int
            ) {
                Thread {
                    val itemsList = db?.costDAO()!!.getByName(s.toString())

                    runOnUiThread {

                            recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter(this@MainActivity, itemsList)
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    }
                }.start()
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) { }
```

Now i can just search one item, item displays, and after changing edit text it disappears, i want it to stay, i want every item I've searched for to automatically be added to RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the search string in wildcards (it should at least have a trailing wildcard `%`):

```
val itemsList = db?.costDAO()!!.getByName("%" + s.toString() + "%")
```

it's common to query only eg. when `s.length() > 3`, in order not to query for single characters; while 3-4 characters already might turn up rather relevant record sets.